# How to avoid/prevent the system to draw/redraw/refresh/paint a WPF window

Tags: wpf, window, system, draw

I have an Application WPF with Visual C# (using visual studio 2010) and I want to draw OpenGL scenes on the WPF window itself. As for the OpenGL drawinf itself, I'm able to draw it w/o problems, meaning, I can create GL render context from the WPF main window itself (no additional OpenGL control, no win32 window inside WPF window), use GL commands and use swapbuffer (all this is done inside a dll - using C - I created myself). However, I have an annoying flickering when, for example, I resize the window. I overrided the OnRender method to re-draw with opengl, but after this, the window is redraw with the background color. It's likely that the system is automatically redrawing it. With WindowForms I'm able to prevent the system to redraw automatically (defining some ControlStyles to true or false, like UserPaint = true, AllPaintingInWmPaint = true, Opaque = true, ResizeRedraw = true, DoubleBuffer = false), but, aside setting Opacity to 1, I don't know how to do all that with WPF. I was hoping that overriding OnRender with no operations inside it would avoid redrawin, but somehow the system still draw the background.

Do anyone know how to prevent system to redraw the window?

Thx for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Background of the window to null:

```
this.Background=null;
```

You can also try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFOpenGL.aspx).

Comment: Hi Andy, well, when I do so the only difference is that the window color changes from the default white to the black color. The system redrawing still have the last word, a black background window (no matter the foreground color).

Comment: "You can also try this." I've already read this article, but it does not use the WPF main window for oGL, but a second winform or win32 window, which I would like to avoid (I don't care about WPF controls, I'm actually using WPF for touch support only).